# How to use grep to find line with single digit on the end?

Tags: linux, grep

This is how my data file looks like:

```
  names   adress number score
  blabla  blabla 1212        5
  blabla  blabla 1212      4.5
```

I need to extract lines with 5 on the end of the line
When I try to use grep -e 5$ i get also lines with 4.5.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find lines that have whitespace before the 5? Try the whitespace character `\s`

```
 grep -e \s5$
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicly similar than Evan's answer. Just using the posix whitespace class instead of \s:

```
grep -E "[[:space:]]5$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Evan's answer is the way. For completeness, here you have other ways:

`sed`: just print those ending with *space* + 5.

```
$ sed -n '/\s5$/p' file
  blabla  blabla 1212        5
```

`awk`: just print those whose last field is exactly `5`. I use `"5"` because otherwise it would be a numeric comparison and `05` would match.

```
$ awk '$NF=="5"' file
  blabla  blabla 1212        5
```

`grep`: the same, but quoting:

```
$ grep "\s5$" file
  blabla  blabla 1212        5
```